# Index numpy array by multiple boolean masks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-logic

I have an array x and a list of filters (array of booleans same length as x):

```
x = np.random.rand(10)
filt1 = x > .2
filt2 = x < .5
filt3 = x % 2 > .02
filters_list = [filt1, filt2, filt3]
```

I want to create a filter that is the logical AND of all filters in `filters_list` so the output should be

```
output = x[filt1 & filt2 & filt3]
```

How do I create the filter `filt1 & filt2 & filt3` from `filters_list` assuming `len(filters_list)` is arbitrary?

Comment: look at `np.logical_and`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.all()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all) with the axis and the list of filters.

```
x = np.arange(10)
filt1 = x > 2
filt2 = x < 9
filt3 = (x % 2) == 1
filters_list = np.all([filt1, filt2, filt3], axis=0)
x[filters_list]

#array([3, 5, 7])
```